# USB Mouse suddenly stopped working 16.04

Tags: usb, mouse

About a week ago my USB mouse stopped working. It shows power and works for approx 1 second after plugging it in. I took 16.04 a few months ago while it was still in beta and have been updating it since with very few problems. However in order to get it to function after that I have to use the terminal to issue

```
sudo rmmod usbhid
sudo modprobe usbhid
```

It does not seem to be a problem with a newer mouse although the one I am having issues is is not that old.

Output of lsusb when mouse is plugged in - power light on but non responsive.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b8a Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 15d9:0a4c Trust International B.V. USB+PS/2 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It's not a big deal as I have a workaround but would be interested to find out why its happening.

Output from dmesg

```
[11860.450870] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[11865.825215] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[11865.956965] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=15d9, idProduct=0a4c
[11865.956968] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[11865.956969] usb 1-2: Product:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE
[11865.957078] usb 1-2: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[11865.959228] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:15D9:0A4C.0003/input/input18
[11865.959383] hid-generic 0003:15D9:0A4C.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[11866.472640] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.480624] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.488650] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.496634] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.504634] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.512614] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.520655] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.528649] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.536634] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[11866.544659] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
.
.
.

##### 400+ LINES OF THE SAME ##########
.
.
.
[11913.057603] usb 1-2: input irq status -75 received
[12068.629678] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[12076.999960] usbhid: unknown parameter 'id' ignored
[12077.001568] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:15D9:0A4C.0004/input/input19
[12077.001690] hid-generic 0003:15D9:0A4C.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[12077.001708] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[12077.001709] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[12186.835154] usbcore: deregistering interface driver usbhid
[12186.900747] input:  USB OPTICAL MOUSE as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:15D9:0A4C.0005/input/input20
[12186.956426] hid-generic 0003:15D9:0A4C.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [ USB OPTICAL MOUSE] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[12186.956488] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[12186.956489] usbhid: USB HID core driver
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug and I have personally faced it and reported it to the GNOME Software developer, the problem exactly is in fwupd package.

If you want to solve it and remove fwupd, run:

```
$ sudo apt remove fwupd
$ sudo killall fwupd
```

Then re-plug your USB mouse and it should be working.
Here's the bug report, please add your comments there: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1322259

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue when I open Ubuntu Software! 400+ of the same lines create when you move your mouse, you can see it by running this:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

as you can see when you move it new lines will be shown.
I don't know what the hell is going on when I open Ubuntu Software and what it does to my mouse. But removing and adding again the driver from kernel fix it after I close the Ubuntu Software. I Also tried to unplug it and plug it again to the same port and no hope but the other ports will do fine when the Ubuntu Software is close.